# If $X=PX'$, then P is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let V be a set of all $n \times 1$ column vectors and $X,X'$ is in V. If there exist $n\times n$ matrix P such that $$X=PX'$$
>   then can we say P is invertible?

I guess that $X=0 \Leftrightarrow X'=0$ but don't know how to show it.

> I edited that there is a relation between $X,X'$ for certain matrix P such that $$X=PX'$$

Comment: Why should this be true? Let $P$ be any $n\times n$ matrix, let $X'$ be any column vector and for $X$ put $X = PX'$. All the conditions of your conjecture is now satisfied - for all possible $P$ (also the non-invertible).

Answer (score 3):

This is not true.
For example, Take $X=0_{n\times 1}$, $X'$ can be anything, and $P=0_{n\times n}$.

Obviously $X=PX'$, but $P=0$ and therefore not invertible.

Comment: sorry, i edited the condition

Comment: @cokecokecoke The current version of this answer answers the current version of your question.